# Check cookie based on form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies

I have an embedded form on a page.  When the page loads, it needs to check if the user is cookied.  If the user is cookied, alert them.  If not, allow the person to submit the form and then cookie them.  With the code below, upon page load, the user is cookied and always looks like a return user despite only invoking the cookieing function upon submit.

```
<body onLoad="checkCookieExists()">
<h1>Cookie test</h1>

<p>When the form loads, it will tell you if you've been here before based on the cookie.</p>

<form id="myForm" action="/">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

<script>
function checkCookieExists() {
      if (document.cookie.indexOf('front-row=submitted')== -1 ) {
       // New user
        alert("this is your first time");
          console.log("existcookienew");
    }
       else {
      // They've been here before.
        alert("hello again");

    }
}

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", checkCookie());

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function checkCookie() {
     setCookie("front-row", "submitted", 30);
}

</script>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to correct is the following one

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", checkCookie);
```

You should give the function `checkCookie`, not the result of the function call `checkCookie()`.

**edition to explain**

`addEventListener` expect two params

- a string as event type
- a function as 'how to react'.

`checkCookie` is a function.
`checkCookie()` is a call to the function that equals the result of the function.

So if you write

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", checkCookie());
```

it's like writing (in this case)

```
checkCookie();
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", undefined);
```

Now why is it not working after the first bug resolved? Well, what does `checkCookie`? Just read it...  well it set a cookie. Why are you writing the cookie there? I suppose you want to write it with a server. At least call this method `setCookie`.

Then... then... just erase this code starts from scratch, iteratively. All that is very unclear and I really doubt it matches your real goal.

Comment: Can you explain the difference in the end result of checkCookie and checkCookie() in that instance?  When I made that update, it now doesn't ever invoke the function upon submitting it.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. I'm a bit confused by the last paragraph - what is erasing my code and starting from scratch?  In the end product, if users have the cookie, I will add a redirect instead of an alert, so they won't be able to see the page twice.  When I use `setCookie` instead of `checkCookie`, it invokes the function without submitting the form.  Also, you mention that I should write the cookie with a server.  Can you further explain that?

Comment: I got it to work by changing the function name.  I did not have to change the functions or write the cookie with the server.   `document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", checkCookie);`